# is there a way to convert .wav file to base64 string from client side?

Tags: base64

I have a requirement where the user can upload .wav format or .mp3 format file to database, since i have to send only the base64 string to store in database am searching for this.

Answer (score 2):

i developed the html script which is simple:
you have two function which convert from normal string to base64 and vice versa.

`var base64str = btoa( arrayBuffer);`
this function will convert to base 64.

`var basestr = atob( base64str);` and this function will convert base64 string to normal string.

to send the file you will use variable base64str.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>File to base64</title>

</head>
<body>

    <input type='file' onchange='openFile(event)'>
<script>

    var openFile = function(event) {
    var input = event.target; 
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(){
    var arrayBuffer = reader.result;

    var base64str = btoa( arrayBuffer);
    var basestr = atob( base64str)

    document.getElementById("base64textarea").value  = base64str;
    document.getElementById("Asciiareah").value  = basestr;
    };

    reader.readAsBinaryString(input.files[0]);
  };
</script>

   <textarea id="base64textarea" cols="40" rows="20"></textarea>
   <textarea id="Asciiareah" cols="40" rows="20"></textarea>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help:)